# Append lists prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Given the list as input (in the format mentioned below) , I need to get the output that is a simple list of lists, If the given input list is empty then the predicate should return an empty list,

Given the input

```
[[[a,b],[c]],[[d,e]],[[g,h],[j,k]],[[h,k,l,l]]]
```

I need to get the output

```
[[a,b],[c],[d,e],[g,h],[j,k],[h,k,l,l]]
```

I am having trouble performing recursion,

The code I tried is below,

```
function([],X):-append([],X,X).
function([Head|Tail],X):-
                first(Tail,A),
                append(Head,A,X),
                removehead(Tail,C),
                function(C,X).
```

where the predicates first returns first element of the list, removehead removes the first element of the list.

Comment: Given the list as input (in the format mentioned above) , I need to get the output that is a simple list of lists, If the given input list is empty then the predicate should return an empty list.

Comment: Put this in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a fair attempt in the code you have shared. Here are the things that you need to improve:

1. The predicate name `fucntion` describes the fact that this predicate has one solution whenever the first argument is a list. This is typically done in the documentation, e.g. `%! function(+Nested:list, -Denested:list) is det.`
2. `append([], X, X)` is true by definition if `X` is a list, so it is superfluous here.
3. What are `first/2`, `removehead/2`? If you want to instantiate to the first element of a list, you can also write the clause head argument as `[Head,A|C]`. Then you also do not need to remove the head from `Tail` explicitly.

Once I make alterations based on the above I come up with the following code:

```
%! denest(+Nested:list, -Denested:list) is det.

denest([], []).
denest([H|T1], L):-
  denest(T1, T2),
  append(H, T2, L).
```

Example run:

```
?- denest([[[a,b],[c]],[[d,e]],[[g,h],[j,k]],[[h,k,l,l]]], L).
   L = [[a, b], [c], [d, e], [g, h], [j, k], [h, k, l|...]].
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't know about the way to write the head argument as you have mentioned and that prompted me to write first/2 and removehead/2 .

Comment: @sand Prolog is a very elegant language: the longer you program in it, the shorter your programs will become :-)